# Break a line in a TextBox (TextArea) from a Model variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

On an ASP.NET MVC I have a textarea as follows:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Text, 12, 12, null)
```

On the controller I am defining the model as:

```
NewPostModel model = new NewPostModel() { Text = @"First line\r\n\r\nan\[x \cdot y\]" };
```

But in the view I don't have a break line inside the textbox.

The text appears all in the same line. Why?

**UPDATE**

I isolated the problem ... If it don't use @ before the string then it works.

The problem is that in the string I have parts as [ and ( ...

And then I get an error: Unrecognized escape sequence.

How can I solve this?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can edit your string, you can do something like this and avoid so the use of the @ :

```
var model = new NewPostModel() { Text = "First line\r\n\r\nan\\[x \\cdot y\\]" };
```